# Keyframe on modal interfering with full screen video

Tags: javascript, css, video, modal-dialog, keyframe

So I'm using a modal that has a video player inside it. Everything works fine, except when I go full screen, the video seems to show up behind every other element.

Here's the video within the modal:
[image: within modal]

And here's the page after making the video full screen:
[image: full screen]

I went through and changed everything in the modal's css file until I found a version that works. Turns out it's the entering keyframe animation:

```
@keyframes rodal-fade-enter {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
.rodal-fade-enter {
    animation: rodal-fade-enter both ease-in;
}
```

When I remove this animation, full screen works fine. However, the entering animation looks super choppy. Is there an alternate animation I can use that does the same thing as fading in, but doesn't mess with the full screen video?

I'm not even sure why this animation messes with full screen in the first place, so any explanations are incredibly welcome.

The modal I'm using is https://github.com/chenjiahan/rodal.

Here's a snippet to replicate the issue:

```js
/* =============================== Rodal v1.6.1 https://chenjiahan.github.com/rodal =============================== */

// env
const inBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
const UA = inBrowser && window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
const isIE9 = UA && UA.indexOf('msie 9.0') > 0;

const Dialog = props => {
  const animation = (
    props.animationType === 'enter'
    ? props.enterAnimation
    : props.leaveAnimation) || props.animation;
  const className = `rodal-dialog rodal-${animation}-${props.animationType}`;
  const CloseButton = props.showCloseButton
    ? <span className="rodal-close" onClick={props.onClose}/>
    : null;
  const {width, height, measure, duration, customStyles} = props;
  const style = {
    width: width + measure,
    height: height + measure,
    animationDuration: duration + 'ms',
    WebkitAnimationDuration: duration + 'ms'
  };
  const mergedStyles = {
    ...style,
    ...customStyles
  };

  return (<div style={mergedStyles} className={className}>
    {props.children}
    {CloseButton}
  </div>)
};

class Rodal extends React.Component {

  static defaultProps = {
    width: 400,
    height: 240,
    measure: 'px',
    visible: false,
    showMask: true,
    closeOnEsc: false,
    closeMaskOnClick: true,
    showCloseButton: true,
    animation: 'zoom',
    enterAnimation: '',
    leaveAnimation: '',
    duration: 300,
    className: '',
    customStyles: {},
    customMaskStyles: {}
  };

  state = {
    isShow: false,
    animationType: 'leave'
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.visible) {
      this.enter();
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (!this.props.visible && nextProps.visible) {
      this.enter();
    } else if (this.props.visible && !nextProps.visible) {
      this.leave();
    }
  }

  enter() {
    this.setState({isShow: true, animationType: 'enter'});
  }

  leave() {
    this.setState(
      isIE9
      ? {
        isShow: false
      }
      : {
        animationType: 'leave'
      });
  }

  onKeyUp = event => {
    if (this.props.closeOnEsc && event.keyCode === 27) {
      this.props.onClose();
    }
  }

  animationEnd = event => {
    if (this.state.animationType === 'leave') {
      this.setState({isShow: false});
    } else if (this.props.closeOnEsc) {
      this.el.focus();
    }

    if (event.target === this.el) {
      const {onAnimationEnd} = this.props;
      onAnimationEnd && onAnimationEnd();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {props, state} = this;
    const onClick = props.closeMaskOnClick
      ? props.onClose
      : null;
    const mask = props.showMask
      ? <div className="rodal-mask" style={props.customMaskStyles} onClick={onClick}/>
      : null;
    const style = {
      display: state.isShow
        ? ''
        : 'none',
      animationDuration: props.duration + 'ms',
      WebkitAnimationDuration: props.duration + 'ms'
    };

    return (<div style={style} className={"rodal rodal-fade-" + state.animationType + ' ' + props.className} onAnimationEnd={this.animationEnd} tabIndex="-1" ref={el => {
        this.el = el;
      }} onKeyUp={this.onKeyUp}>
      {mask}
      <Dialog {...props} animationType={state.animationType}>
        {props.children}
      </Dialog>
    </div>)
  }
}

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      modalIsOpen: false
    }
  }

  openModal = () => {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: true})
  }

  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: false})
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
      <button onClick={this.openModal}>Open modal</button>
      <Rodal visible={this.state.modalIsOpen} onClose={this.closeModal} closeOnEsc={true} animation='door'>
        <video id='my-video' src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" controls></video>
      </Rodal>
    </div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.rodal,
.rodal-mask {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}

.rodal {
    position: fixed;
}

/* -- mask -- */
.rodal-mask {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

/* -- dialog -- */
.rodal-dialog {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 101;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.rodal-dialog:focus {
    outline: none;
}

/* -- close button -- */
.rodal-close {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 16px;
    right: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

.rodal-close:before,
.rodal-close:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -1px;
    background: #999;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: background .2s;
    transition: background .2s;
}

.rodal-close:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.rodal-close:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.rodal-close:hover:before,
.rodal-close:hover:after {
    background: #333;
}

/* -- fade -- */
@-webkit-keyframes rodal-fade-enter {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes rodal-fade-enter {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
}

.rodal-fade-enter {
    -webkit-animation: rodal-fade-enter both ease-in;
    animation: rodal-fade-enter both ease-in;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rodal-fade-leave {
    to {
        opacity: 0
    }
}

@keyframes rodal-fade-leave {
    to {
        opacity: 0
    }
}

.rodal-fade-leave {
    -webkit-animation: rodal-fade-leave both ease-out;
    animation: rodal-fade-leave both ease-out;
}

/* -- zoom -- */
@-webkit-keyframes rodal-zoom-enter {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
        transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    }
}

@keyframes rodal-zoom-enter {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
        transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    }
}

.rodal-zoom-enter {
    -webkit-animation: rodal-zoom-enter both cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1.5);
    animation: rodal-zoom-enter both cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1.5);
}

@-webkit-keyframes rodal-zoom-leave {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
        transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    }
}

@keyframes rodal-zoom-leave {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
        transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    }
}

.rodal-zoom-leave {
    -webkit-animation: rodal-zoom-leave both;
    animation: rodal-zoom-leave both;
}

/* -- slideDown -- */
@-webkit-keyframes rodal-slideDown-enter {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -100px, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes rodal-slideDown-enter {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -100px, 0);
    }
}

.rodal-slideDown-enter {
    -webkit-animation: rodal-slideDown-enter both cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1.5);
    animation: rodal-slideDown-enter both cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1.5);
}

@-webkit-keyframes rodal-slideDown-leave {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -100px, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes rodal-slideDown-leave {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -100px, 0);
    }
}

.rodal-slideDown-leave {
    -webkit-animation: rodal-slideDown-leave both;
    animation: rodal-slideDown-leave both;
}

/* -- slideLeft -- */
@-webkit-keyframes rodal-slideLeft-enter {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-150px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-150px, 0, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes rodal-slideLeft-enter {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-150px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-150px, 0, 0);
    }
}

.rodal-slideLeft-enter {
    -webkit-animation: rodal-slideLeft-enter both cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1.5);
    animation: rodal-slideLeft-enter both cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1.5);
}

@-webkit-keyframes rodal-slideLeft-leave {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-150px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-150px, 0, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes rodal-slideLeft-leave {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-150px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-150px, 0, 0);
    }
}

.rodal-slideLeft-leave {
    -webkit-animation: rodal-slideLeft-leave both;
    animation: rodal-slideLeft-leave both;
}

/* -- slideRight -- */
@-webkit-keyframes rodal-slideRight-enter {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(150px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(150px, 0, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes rodal-slideRight-enter {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(150px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(150px, 0, 0);
    }
}

.rodal-slideRight-enter {
    -webkit-animation: rodal-slideRight-enter both cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1.5);
    animation: rodal-slideRight-enter both cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1.5);
}

@-webkit-keyframes rodal-slideRight-leave {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(150px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(150px, 0, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes rodal-slideRight-leave {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(150px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(150px, 0, 0);
    }
}

.rodal-slideRight-leave {
    -webkit-animation: rodal-slideRight-leave both;
    animation: rodal-slideRight-leave both;
}

/* -- slideUp -- */
@-webkit-keyframes rodal-slideUp-enter {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 100px, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes rodal-slideUp-enter {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 100px, 0);
    }
}

.rodal-slideUp-enter {
    -webkit-animation: rodal-slideUp-enter both cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1.5);
    animation: rodal-slideUp-enter both cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1.5);
}

@-webkit-keyframes rodal-slideUp-leave {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 100px, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes rodal-slideUp-leave {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 100px, 0);
    }
}

.rodal-slideUp-leave {
    -webkit-animation: rodal-slideUp-leave both;
    animation: rodal-slideUp-leave both;
}

/* -- flip -- */
@-webkit-keyframes rodal-flip-enter {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 60deg);
        transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 60deg);
    }
    70% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -15deg);
        transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -15deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
        transform: perspective(400px);
    }
}

@keyframes rodal-flip-enter {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 60deg);
        transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 60deg);
    }
    70% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -15deg);
        transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -15deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
        transform: perspective(400px);
    }
}

.rodal-flip-enter {
    -webkit-animation: rodal-flip-enter both ease-in;
    animation: rodal-flip-enter both ease-in;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
    backface-visibility: visible !important;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rodal-flip-leave {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
        transform: perspective(400px);
    }
    30% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -15deg);
        transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -15deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 45deg);
        transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 45deg);
    }
}

@keyframes rodal-flip-leave {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
        transform: perspective(400px);
    }
    30% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -15deg);
        transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -15deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 45deg);
        transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 45deg);
    }
}

.rodal-flip-leave {
    -webkit-animation: rodal-flip-leave both;
    animation: rodal-flip-leave both;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
    backface-visibility: visible !important;
}

/* -- rotate -- */
@-webkit-keyframes rodal-rotate-enter {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -180deg) scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
        transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -180deg) scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    }
}

@keyframes rodal-rotate-enter {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -180deg) scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
        transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -180deg) scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    }
}

.rodal-rotate-enter {
    -webkit-animation: rodal-rotate-enter both;
    animation: rodal-rotate-enter both;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rodal-rotate-leave {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 180deg) scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
        transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 180deg) scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    }
}

@keyframes rodal-rotate-leave {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 180deg) scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
        transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 180deg) scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    }
}

.rodal-rotate-leave {
    -webkit-animation: rodal-rotate-leave both;
    animation: rodal-rotate-leave both;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
}

/* -- door -- */
@-webkit-keyframes rodal-door-enter {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1);
        transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1);
    }
}

@keyframes rodal-door-enter {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1);
        transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1);
    }
}

.rodal-door-enter {
    -webkit-animation: rodal-door-enter both cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1.5);
    animation: rodal-door-enter both cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1.5);
}

@-webkit-keyframes rodal-door-leave {
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(.01, 1, 1);
        transform: scale3d(.01, 1, 1);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(0, 1, .1);
        transform: scale3d(0, 1, .1);
    }
}

@keyframes rodal-door-leave {
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(.01, 1, 1);
        transform: scale3d(.01, 1, 1);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(0, 1, .1);
        transform: scale3d(0, 1, .1);
    }
}

.rodal-door-leave {
    -webkit-animation: rodal-door-leave both;
    animation: rodal-door-leave both;
}

#my-video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'></div>
```